# fread variable max of 8192

Tags: php, size, fread

So what I have here is a function that reads the output from a socket.

```
$content=$this->tsread(256);

function tsread($size,$timeout=1)
{
    global $handle;
    $start=microtime(true);
    do
    {
        usleep($size*10);
        $data=fread($handle,1);
        $info=stream_get_meta_data($handle);
    }
    while ((microtime(true)-$start)<$timeout and $info['timed_out']);
    do
    {
        usleep($size*10);
        if ($info['unread_bytes']>$size)
        {
            $data.=fread($handle,$size);
        }
        else
        {
            $data.=fread($handle,$info['unread_bytes']);
        }            
        $info=stream_get_meta_data($handle);
    }
    while ($info['unread_bytes']>0);
    return $data;
}
```

Usually, this successfully reads the output but recently the output from the socket has been larger and the function doesn't successfully read it all.

When I do strlen($data) I get a value of 8192.

Is there a max variable size? Or is there something in the function that limits the length of $data to 8192?

Answer (score 0):

> if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file,
>   at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size
>   (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the
>   size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk
>    [size](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

Comment: I set the chunk size to 256 with `tsread(256);` and `$data.=fread($handle,$size);` right?

Comment: @codexo10Z have this answer your question? if you have another one how to handle this ask another question with the whole code, he class and/or framework you're using